# $\mu$-polystable locally free sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces

In Huybrechts and Lehn's book "The Geometry of Moduli Space of Sheaves", a sheaf $E \in Ob(Coh_{d,d-1}(X))$ is polystable if $E \cong \bigoplus E_{i}$ in $Coh_{d,d-1}(X)$, where the
sheaves $E_{i}$ are stable in $Coh_{d,d-1}(X)$ and $\mu(E_{i})=\mu(E)$.

Here is a corollary:

A locally free sheaf $E$ on $X$ is polystable in $Coh_{d,d-1}(X)$, if and only if $E \cong \bigoplus E_{i}$ in $Coh(X)$, where the sheaves $E_{i}$ are $\mu$-stable locally free sheaves
with $\mu(E_{i})=\mu(E)$

I can deduce $E \cong \bigoplus E_{i}^{\vee \vee}$ in $Coh(X)$ from $E \cong \bigoplus E_{i}$ in $Coh_{d,d-1}(X)$, and since a summand of a locally free sheaf is locally free, $E_{i}^{\vee\vee}$ are locally free sheaves,but they may not be $\mu$-stable. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see anything missing or contradictory in what you wrote. A sheaf is (poly-)stable iff its reflexization is (poly-)stable. It would help, though, if you have explained what $Coh_{d,d-1}$ is.

Comment: $Coh_{d,d-1}(X)$ is the quotient category $Cod_{d}(X)/Coh_{d-1}(X)$

Comment: Then a locally free sheaf cannot belong to $Coh_{d,d-1}$ unless $d=dim X$.